Matrix Calculus, finding the weights of a 2 layered non-linear neural network, with sigmoid activation functions
I'm working on a method to calculate weights of a non-linear 2 layer neural network in 1 step, instead of working with the propagation algorithm.
I have chosen to make the non-linearity a sigmoid function. And I already made some progress.
$$
Loss = (pred-y)^2\\
pred = A(A(X\cdot B_2)\cdot B_1)\\
A(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\\
A^{-1}(x)=-ln(\frac{1-x}{x})\\
L(B_1,B_2)=(A(A(X\cdot B_2)\cdot B_1) - y)^2\\
L(B_1,B_2)=(A(X\cdot B_2)\cdot B_1 - A^{-1}(y))^2\\
$$
A^{-1}(x) is the inverse function of the sigmoid.
$$
L(B_1,B_2)=(A(X\cdot B_2)\cdot B_1 - A^{-1}(y))^2=\\
(A(X\cdot B_2)\cdot B_1 - A^{-1}(y))^T\cdot(A(X\cdot B_2)\cdot B_1 - A^{-1}(y))=\\
(B_1^T\cdot A(X\cdot B_2)^T - A^{-1}(y)^T)\cdot(A(X\cdot B_2)\cdot B_1 - A^{-1}(y))=\\
...\\
B_1^T\cdot A(X\cdot B_2)^T\cdot A(X\cdot B_2)\cdot B_1-2B_1^T\cdot A(X\cdot B_2)^T\cdot A^{-1}(y) + A^{-1}(y)^T\cdot A^{-1}(y)
$$
then we calculate the derivative with respect to $B_1$
$$
\frac{\partial L(B_1,B_2)}{\partial B_1} = 2A(X\cdot B_2)^T \cdot A(X\cdot B_2) \cdot B_1 - A(x\cdot B_2)^T \cdot A^{-1}(y)=0\\
B_1=(A(X\cdot B_2)^T\cdot A(X\cdot B_2))^{-1}\cdot A(X\cdot B_2)^T\cdot A^{-1}(y)
$$
we simpely now have calculated the standard linear regression, but the $B_2$ is still in the formula. I have put $B_1$ back into the formula of $L(B_1,B_2)$. And then I was simplifying the expression. This is the expression that I got:
$$
L(B_2)=-A^{-1}(y)^T\cdot A(X\cdot B_2)\cdot (A(X\cdot B_2)^T\cdot A(X\cdot B_2))^{-1}\cdot A(X\cdot B_2)^T\cdot A^{-1}(y)+A^{-1}(y)^T\cdot A^{-1}(y)
$$
I now need to calculate $\frac{dL(B_2)}{B_2}=0$ and then solve for $B_2$, but i'm not that proficient at matrix calculus, because I haven't done that at university.

Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/470053/matrix-calculus-finding-the-weights-of-a-2-layered-non-linear-neural-network-w
